# How to set the row count to th right of the QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a tableView which gets it's data from sqlite database. How can i move the row numbers to the right side of the tableView?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out, Actually in order to do that, we should set a `layoutDirection` to our widget which changes the layout direction which in my case would be `Qt.RightToLeft`.